# An error occurred during the signature verification

Tags: appcenter

The AppCenter has problems updating. This type of error appears multiple times here, but I think they're all a bit different?

I get the following notice:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/xmpp:/dino/xUbuntu_18.04  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 62EB1A0917280DDF network OBS Project <network@build.opensuse.org>
E: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/xmpp:/dino/xUbuntu_18.04  InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 62EB1A0917280DDF network OBS Project
```

This seems more specific than the other questions. Can anybody tell me what went wrong (and how to fix it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by following the steps on https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=network:messaging:xmpp:dino&package=dino

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/xmpp:/dino/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/network:messaging:xmpp:dino.list"
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:messaging:xmpp:dino/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```

Not sure why this failed though? Was the key renewed? How can I (a user) tell?

Answer (score 0):

That is the OpenSuse PPA, not elementary os. Looks like you added that one for installing OBS. As flatpack support is added, I would go with that, to remove modifications to the system and keep it stable.

Comment: how can I tell what the modifications are?

Comment: Actually I probably did this for dino.im for which I don't think there is flatpak support (https://github.com/dino/dino/pull/343)

Comment: @Friso You can find them in /etc/apt/sources.list or as a separate file in /etc/apt/sources.list It is mostly a line like: `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/xmpp:/dino/xUbuntu_18.04 bionic main` or similar. But I saw you already solved this? Great to see.